# Recording what the user listen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to add something that record what the iphone is playing, i understand that i need something that called audioQueue.

i am using ExtAudioFileRef in my app for playing songs.

Comment: I just have to ask: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much for me to type here. But see these links, they really helped me...

1. [**Playing Audio on an iPad using AVAudioPlayer**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Playing_Audio_on_an_iPad_using_AVAudioPlayer_%28Xcode_4%29)
2. [**Recording Audio on an iPad with AVAudioRecorder**](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPad_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28Xcode_4%29)

Hope this helps...